# Why does `128u8.checked_shl(1)` return `Some(0)`?

Tags: rust, integer-overflow

I was under the impression that the `.checked_*(_)` methods of the integral types were there to help avoid overflow. However, the `.checked_shl(u32)` method happily shifts out the last bit of the example above.

Is my impression wrong? What is that method *for*?

(Also wanted to add that to avoid overflow on shifts, one can check if `((~0) >> rhs) >= self` at least for unsigned types)

Comment: My guess is that it's covering the C feature where shifting by more than the bit size is UB, but left shift is considered more of a bit manipulation operation than an arithmetic one, so it's not counted as arithmetic overflow.  But I agree it's not necessarily the only obvious choice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because it checks only the shift amount. From the [docs](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.u8.html#method.checked_shl),

> `None` if `rhs` is larger than or equal to the number of bits in `self`.

So by design it lets you shift out bits, it just doesn't let you use invalid shift amounts (or, it lets you, but you get `None`).